# How can i loop over an array to get jquery properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some fields that I want to hide if they are null. I am able to do this with:

```
if (json[0].incendio_edificio == null) {
  $("#dIncendio_edificio").parent().parent().hide();
}

if (json[0].hvct_edificio == null) {
  $("#dHvct_edificio").parent().parent().hide();
}

if (json[0].granizo_edificio == null) {
  $("#dGranizo_edificio").parent().parent().hide();
}
```

What I want to do is put the fields inside a matrix and do the conditional inside a loop, like this:

```
const campos_poliza = [
                         [json[0].incendio_edificio, $("#dIncendio_edificio")],
                         [json[0].hvct_edificio, $("#dHvct_edificio")],
                         [json[0].granizo_edificio, $("#dGranizo_edificio")],
                      ];

for (var x in campos_poliza){
  if (x[0] == null) {
    x[1].parent().parent().hide();
  }
}
```

This doesn´t give any errors but it keeps showing null fields. How can I achieve this?
The html is:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">
    <span class="text-bold text-blue">Incendio Edificio:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col s9">
    <span id="dIncendio_edificio"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">
    <span class="text-bold text-blue">HVCT Edificio:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col s9">
    <span id="dHvct_edificio"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">
    <span class="text-bold text-blue">Granizo Edificio:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col s9">
    <span id="dGranizo_edificio"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML.

Comment: Can you show your JSON? Maybe values are not null but empty strings?

Comment: Can you update the question to a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `for (var x in campos_poliza)` , `x` is the index of array, which is 0, 1, 2...

This might be what you need:

```
for (var x of campos_poliza) {
  if (x[0] == null) {
    x[1].parent().parent().hide();
  }
}
```

Or

```
campos_poliza.forEach(x => {
  if (x[0] == null) {
    x[1].parent().parent().hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not toggle if existing

```js
const obj = [{ incendio_edificio:null, hvct_edificio : "not null", granizo_edificio : null }]
Object.entries(obj[0]).forEach(([key,val]) => { 
  const sel = `#d${key.slice(0,1).toUpperCase()}${key.slice(1)}`; 
  console.log(key,val,sel)
  const $elem = $(sel)
  if ($elem) $elem.closest(".row").toggle(val!=null)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">
    <span class="text-bold text-blue">Incendio Edificio:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col s9">
    <span id="dIncendio_edificio"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">
    <span class="text-bold text-blue">HVCT Edificio:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col s9">
    <span id="dHvct_edificio"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s3">
    <span class="text-bold text-blue">Granizo Edificio:</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col s9">
    <span id="dGranizo_edificio"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```